# How to automate sending attachments through GMail using Selenium java

Tags: maven, selenium, gmail, email-attachments, apache-commons-email

I am doing test automations for the first time, and I want to be able to automate gmail and send an email with an attachment. I am using selenium web driver, cucumber and google chrome to run the tests. My IDE is intelliJ. My tests work up until I have to attach the file:

```
public void givenOnAmazonProductPage() throws Throwable {
    setupSeleniumWebDrivers();
    goTo(PRODUCT_URL);
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    goTo(PRODUCT_URL);
    //driver.wait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("subjectbox")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("subjectbox")).sendKeys("efgh");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
    //driver.close();
    //click on attachment
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='a1 aaA aMZ']")).click();
    //use autoit tool to attach a file
```

this is where i try to attach the file that is on my desktop but it doesnt seem to work

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:Desktop/6c3bfdec92fad54896275802f938bd83.29.jpg");
    // enter the file path onto the file-selection input field


    Thread.sleep(10000); //wait for 10sec to upload file
}
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong to attach the file?

Answer (score 1):

This should be your `autoit` .exe path not .jpg path. You need to create executable `(.exe)` of your autoit scrips and pass as i have mentioned.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path of Autoit exe"); // like "C:\\AutoIt3\\new.exe"
```

Comment: but there is not version of autoit for mac?

Answer (score 0):

There are several simple ways to automate sending of an email with an attachment even without using *Selenium* as follows:

- If you are using [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) there are separate plugins for **GMail** through `smtp` settings.
- If you are using *Maven* you can use the **postman** plugin.
- Using **commons email api** directly from your *Test Code*.

In this answer I will explain about using the *commons email api* through *Maven*.

---

### Commons Email

[Commons Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) aims to provide a API for sending email. It is built on top of the Java Mail API, which it aims to simplify.

Some of the mail classes that are provided are as follows:

- `SimpleEmail` - This class is used to send basic text based emails.
- `MultiPartEmail` - This class is used to send multipart messages. This allows a text message with attachments either inline or attached.
- `HtmlEmail` - This class is used to send HTML formatted emails. It has all of the capabilities as MultiPartEmail allowing attachments to be easily added. It also supports embedded images.
- `ImageHtmlEmail` - This class is used to send HTML formatted emails with inline images. It has all of the capabilities as HtmlEmail but transform all image references to inline images.
- `EmailAttachment` - This is a simple container class to allow for easy handling of attachments. It is for use with instances of MultiPartEmail and HtmlEmail.
- *Maven Dependency*:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Code Block:

  ```
  package SendEmailAttachments;

  import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
  import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
  import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
  import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

  public class EmailAttachments {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {

          System.out.println("===Test for Sending CommonsEmail started===");  
          // Create the attachment
          EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
          attachment.setPath("C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\bad_indentation.png");
          attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
          attachment.setDescription("Picture of bad indentation");
          attachment.setName("BadIndentation");
          // Create the email message
          MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
          email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
          email.setSmtpPort(465);
          email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("Matthew@Zoltak.in", "Matthew_Zoltak"));
          email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
          email.setFrom("CommonsEmail@gmail.com");
          email.setSubject("CommonsEmail Test");
          email.setMsg("CommonsEmail test mail ... :-)");
          email.addTo("Matthew@Zoltak.in");
          // add the attachment
          email.attach(attachment);
          // send the email
          email.send();
          System.out.println("===Test for Sending CommonsEmail ended===");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ===Test for Sending CommonsEmail started===
  ===Test for Sending CommonsEmail ended===
  ```
- Snapshot:

[image: apache_commons_email_attachment]